# Stylized rim light using compositing

Tags: compositing-nodes, lighting

I'd like to find out how to do a certain hack, or rather a stylized rim light using the least amount of nodes possible, or at least a smart way to do it. I saw an application of this technique in the HERO movie by Daniel Martinez Lara and I tried to replicate it, but failed. Any and help would be appreciated. So my character has an alpha channel and i'd like to acheive the following effect:

from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

As you can see, I'm trying to acheive the rim light effect WITHIN the boundaries of my characters original alpha channel. Also all of my experiments resulted in a nasty thin line on the border of my characters face due to my lack of understanding how to ACTUALLY do the unpremult--> do your hacking--> premult workflow. Thank you for taking the time to help. Have a nice day.

Comment: Have you tried doing something with freestyle?

Comment: Hmm, no not yet, it could be a solution, can i limit the stroke to a certain side of the character, like in my illustration? Thank you for the tip, it might be a better solution.

Comment: I really don't know much about freestyle...I just know it is related, so you could look into that.